# How to use Downloader Middleware in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape some web pages. I wrote my customised **ProxyMiddleware** class in which I implemented my requirement in **process_request(self,request,spider)** method. 
Here is my code(copied):

```
class ProxyMiddleware(scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy):
def __init__(self, proxy_ip=''):
    self.proxy_ip = proxy_ip

def process_request(self,request,spider):
    ip = random.choice(self.proxy_list)
    if ip:
        request.meta['proxy'] = ip
    return request

proxy_list = [list of proxies]
```

Now, I didn't understand how scrapy will consider my implementation instead of default class. After some searching and brainstorming, what I understood is, I need to make changes in settings.py

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'IPProxy.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'IPProxy.IPProxy.spiders.RandomProxy': 600
}
```

For better understanding of my project structure to readers, I added second element in the list with some random value.
My project structure is:

[image]

My question is,

- How to use **DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES** in settings.py correctly
- How to assign the values to the elements in DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES
- How to make scrapy to call my customized code instead of the default

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the, assuming, built-in `HttpProxyMiddleware` Downloader Middleware - set its value in `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` to `None`:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': None,
    'IPProxy.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'IPProxy.IPProxy.spiders.RandomProxy': 600
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. One more ambiguity is, the way I wrote my ProxyMiddleware class's process_request will override the default scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware's process_request.

Comment: DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': None,
    'IPProxy.IPProxy.spiders.ProxyMiddleware': 600,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None,
    'IPProxy.IPProxy.spiders.RotateUserAgentMiddleware':700
}                                                                                                                      Now my code is throughing  No module name UserAgentMiddleware Exception. How can Use my customized class here.

Comment: @Ashwanth I think it is `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware`.

Comment: Changed accordingly, but still throwing the same error

Comment: Their is some ambiguity in calling the customized process_request method . Can you please explain how can I call my process_request methods in RotateUserAgentMiddleware class.

Comment: After few changes in the code, facing this error                                          exceptions.ImportError: No module named IPProxy.spiders                            
2015-10-08 19:29:19 [twisted] CRITICAL: